# HP ENVY X360 wireless/airplane mode button does not light up

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, hp-envy

I upgraded my HP ENVY x360 notebook from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. The wireless button is working correctly, but it does not light up amber/orange while turning off wifi. I have updated, reinstalled Intel virtual button drivers, wifi drivers and HP wireless button drivers, but nothing worked.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the same problem with the mute botton with installing the official driver from HP:
https://support.hp.com/at-de/drivers/selfservice/
I think it will be the same for the flightmode-botton

I found the answer here:
https://youtu.be/O4JcUbUHH3c?t=3m16s